# Do hiring committees look at a candidate's StackExchange account?

Tags: job-search

On StackExchange, some people use their real names, while others hide behind a username.

I was wondering, **do hiring committees look at a candidate's StackExchange account and consider the candidate's activity on these accounts?**

I know committees look at my website, they openly mention this during interviews.  They also ask me about things that they would only know about after seeing my website.  I have yet to connect my real identity with my StackExchange account, because of my reservations about this.

Comment: Anything that shows up when you google someone's name is fair game. So I would say yes, of course, this would happen either by design or happenstance.

Comment: I would say NO. If you don't link your SE account to your website, its difficult to know the real user behind the fancy user name.

Comment: @Coder In fact the OP is asking whether hiring committees would do this had the candidate used their real name.

Comment: In that case, if the user is too frequent then Google shall list the results if you search as "User Name stackexchange". But, I think, which recruiter has this much time to google about you on multiple platforms such as SE, Quora etc. @MassimoOrtolano

Comment: @Coder You don't need to google across multiple platforms: usually activities in widespread network communities show up in the first pages. If you just google my name without further specification, you'll get that I participate to Academia.SE at the first or second page.

Comment: My own experience is that for shortlisted candidate it is usually done (not specifically for SE, but for anything that pops up on Google)

Comment: Assuming you don't have a very common name, shared with at least one semi famous actor, djs, photographers, so on.... When googling my name, I get one link only, on the first 5 pages....

Comment: I am the chair of my department's hiring committee.  Hiring committees (or at least hiring committee _chairs_) definitely google for candidates' names and use the results are (a small) part of their deliberation.

Comment: "Let's see...oh look, they have an SO account...hmm...woah, look at that rep! They must spend all of their time on the site and none of it doing research!" ;-)

Comment: @tonysdg:  Yes, I've sometimes worried people might think that (not that my own rep is really high).  I actually generated most of my math.SE rep during a couple of bouts of flu, when I wasn't up to doing research but didn't want to do no maths whatsoever.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it can happen, though I expect it is rare.

I was recently asked in a job interview whether I was the Tara B on math.SE.  The interviewer who asked the question is also on math.SE, and we have answered some of the same questions.  I have met him in real life and e-mailed him once to ask for a paper, but I had the impression that he primarily remembered me from stackexchange.  (I did get the job, but I doubt that my SE participation was a significant factor.)

(Incidentally, this also demonstrates that even if you only use part of your name on SE, your account might still be noticed.)

Answer (score 5):

As Dan Romik said, anyone can look up anything on Google, so a StackExchange account would possibly be looked at. But I would say that this will only occur rarely, if at all. And it certainly would not amount to a formal indication of either acceptance or rejection.

On the other hand, a StackExchange presence is part of one's online presence as a scientist and so may effect your overall scientific presence, prior to ones application for a job. But it will not be a significant part of the hiring process had the hiring committee do not know your stackexchange participation in advance.

Comment: +1 for the second paragraph.  I have a personal example of the first sentence (see my answer), and I expect that the second sentence would be true in most cases.